# How can validate all new inputs and textares when added? javascript

Tags: javascript, function, validation, input, textarea

How can the added inputs and textareas be validated? Here are my functions for each input. How can it be used for all the input and textare that will be added after clicking the more-experience-btn button?

html code

```
<div class="form-container">
              <div class="input-field">
                <span class="position-valid-icon">
                  <img
                    src="assets/images/icons/valid-icon.svg"
                    alt="valid icon"
                  />
                </span>
                <span class="position-invalid-icon">
                  <img
                    src="assets/images/icons/invalid-icon.svg"
                    alt="invalid icon"
                  />
                </span>
                <label class="label-top label-position" for="position-input"
                  >თანამდებობა</label
                >
                <input
                  class="input position-input"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="თანამდებობა"
                />
                <label class="label-bottom">მინიმუმ 2 სიმბოლო</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field employer">
                <span class="employer-valid-icon">
                  <img
                    src="assets/images/icons/valid-icon.svg"
                    alt="valid icon"
                  />
                </span>
                <span class="employer-invalid-icon">
                  <img
                    src="assets/images/icons/invalid-icon.svg"
                    alt="invalid icon"
                  />
                </span>
                <label class="label-top label-employer" for="employer-input"
                  >დამსაქმებელი</label
                >
                <input
                  class="input employer-input"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="დამსაქმებელი"
                />
                <label class="label-bottom">მინიმუმ 2 სიმბოლო</label>
              </div>
              <div class="date-container">
                <div class="input-field left-date">
                  <label class="label-top label-start-date" for="startdate"
                    >დაწყების რიცხვი</label
                  >
                  <input id="startdate" type="date" class="date start_date" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-field right-date">
                  <label class="label-top label-end-date" for="end-date"
                    >დამთავრების რიცხვი</label
                  >
                  <input type="date" id="end-date" class="date end_date" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field about-field">
                <label class="label-top label-description" for="description"
                  >აღწერა</label
                >
                <textarea
                  class="input about-input description"
                  name="about"
                  placeholder="როლი თანამდებობაზე და ზოგადი აღწერა"
                ></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="border-grey-line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="moreExp"></div>
            <div class="more-experience-btn-container">
              <button
                class="more-btn more-experience-btn"
                onclick="add_more_field(this)"
              >
                მეტი გამოცდილების დამატება
              </button>
            </div>
```

javascript code

position-input validation function

```
function positionValidation() {
  let valid = false;
  if (positionInput.value.length >= 2) {
    positionInput.classList.add("valid");
    positionInput.classList.remove("invalid");
    positionLabel.style.color = "#000000";
    positionValidIcon.classList.add("show");
    positionInvalidIcon.classList.remove("show");
    positionInput.style.outline = "none";
    valid = true;
  } else {
    positionInput.classList.remove("valid");
    positionInput.classList.add("invalid");
    positionLabel.style.color = "#e52f2f";
    positionValidIcon.classList.remove("show");
    positionInvalidIcon.classList.add("show");
    positionInput.style.outline = "none";
  }
  return valid;
}
positionInput.addEventListener("input", positionValidation);
```

employer-input validation function

```
function employerValidation() {
  let valid = false;
  if (employerInput.value.length >= 2) {
    employerInput.classList.add("valid");
    employerInput.classList.remove("invalid");
    employerLabel.style.color = "#000000";
    employerValidIcon.classList.add("show");
    employerInvalidIcon.classList.remove("show");
    employerInput.style.outline = "none";
    valid = true;
  } else {
    employerInput.classList.remove("valid");
    employerInput.classList.add("invalid");
    employerLabel.style.color = "#e52f2f";
    employerValidIcon.classList.remove("show");
    employerInvalidIcon.classList.add("show");
    employerInput.style.outline = "none";
  }
  return valid;
}
employerInput.addEventListener("input", employerValidation);
```

start_date validation function

```
startDateInput.max = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
startDateInput.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
  endtDateInput.min = event.target.value;
  let valid = false;
  if (startDateInput.value != "") {
    startDateInput.classList.add("valid");
    startDateInput.classList.remove("invalid");
    startDateLabel.style.color = "#000000";
    startDateInput.style.outline = "none";
    valid = true;
  } else {
    startDateInput.classList.remove("valid");
    startDateInput.classList.add("invalid");
    startDateLabel.style.color = "#e52f2f";
    startDateInput.style.outline = "none";
  }
  return valid;
});
```

end_date validation function

```
endtDateInput.max = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
endtDateInput.addEventListener("input", function endDateValidation(event) {
  const startDateValue = new Date(startDateInput.value);
  const endDateValue = new Date(event.target.value);

  if (endDateValue < startDateValue) {
    event.target.value = startDateInput.value;
  }

  let valid = false;
  if (endtDateInput.value != "") {
    endtDateInput.classList.add("valid");
    endtDateInput.classList.remove("invalid");
    endtDateLabel.style.color = "#000000";
    endtDateInput.style.outline = "none";
    valid = true;
  } else {
    endtDateInput.classList.remove("valid");
    endtDateInput.classList.add("invalid");
    endtDateLabel.style.color = "#e52f2f";
    endtDateInput.style.outline = "none";
  }
  return valid;
});
```

description textarea validation function

```
function descriptioValidation() {
  let valid = false;
  if (description.value != "") {
    description.classList.add("valid");
    description.classList.remove("invalid");
    descriptionLabel.style.color = "#000000";
    description.style.outline = "none";
    valid = true;
  } else {
    description.classList.remove("valid");
    description.classList.add("invalid");
    descriptionLabel.style.color = "#e52f2f";
    description.style.outline = "none";
  }
  return valid;
}
description.addEventListener("input", descriptioValidation);
```

add new inputs and textarea

```
var countre = 1;
html = ` <div class="form-container -${countre}">
<div class="input-field">
  <span class="position-valid-icon">
    <img
      src="assets/images/icons/valid-icon.svg"
      alt="valid-cion"
    />
  </span>
  <span class="position-invalid-icon">
    <img
      src="assets/images/icons/invalid-icon.svg"
      alt="invalid-icon"
    />
  </span>
  <label class="label-top label-position" for="position-input"
    >თანამდებობა</label
  >
  <input
    class="input position-input-${countre}"
    onkeyup="positionValidation()"
    type="text"
    placeholder="თანამდებობა"
  />
  <label class="label-bottom">მინიმუმ 2 სიმბოლო</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field employer">
  <span class="employer-valid-icon">
    <img
      src="assets/images/icons/valid-icon.svg"
      alt="valid-cion"
    />
  </span>
  <span class="employer-invalid-icon">
    <img
      src="assets/images/icons/invalid-icon.svg"
      alt="invalid-icon"
    />
  </span>
  <label class="label-top label-employer" for="employer-input"
    >დამსაქმებელი</label
  >
  <input
    class="input employer-input-${countre}"
    onkeyup="employerValidation()"
    type="text"
    placeholder="დამსაქმებელი"
  />
  <label class="label-bottom">მინიმუმ 2 სიმბოლო</label>
</div>
<div class="date-container">
  <div class="input-field left-date">
    <label class="label-top label-start-date" for="start_date"
      >დაწყების რიცხვი</label
    >
    <input
      onchange="startDateValidation()"
      type="date"
      class="date start_date-${countre}"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="input-field right-date">
    <label class="label-top label-end-date" for="end_date"
      >დამთავრების რიცხვი</label
    >
    <input
      type="date"
      class="date end_date-${countre}"
      onchange="endtDateValidation()"
    />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="input-field about-field">
  <label class="label-top label-description" for="description"
    >აღწერა</label
  >
  <textarea
    class="input about-input description-${countre}"
    name="about"
    placeholder="როლი თანამდებობაზე და ზოგადი აღწერა"
    onkeyup="descriptioValidation()"
  ></textarea>
</div>
<div class="border-grey-line"></div>`;
function add_more_field() {
  countre += 1;
  var form = document.querySelector(".moreExp");
  form.innerHTML += html;
}

var wholeForm = document.querySelector("#form");
wholeForm.onsubmit = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <div class="input-field">
    <span class="position-valid-icon">
                  <img
                    src="assets/images/icons/valid-icon.svg"
                    alt="valid icon"
                  />
                </span>
    <span class="position-invalid-icon">
                  <img
                    src="assets/images/icons/invalid-icon.svg"
                    alt="invalid icon"
                  />
                </span>
    <label class="label-top label-position" for="position-input">თანამდებობა</label
                >
                <input
                  class="input position-input"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="თანამდებობა"
                />
                <label class="label-bottom">მინიმუმ 2 სიმბოლო</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field employer">
    <span class="employer-valid-icon">
                  <img
                    src="assets/images/icons/valid-icon.svg"
                    alt="valid icon"
                  />
                </span>
    <span class="employer-invalid-icon">
                  <img
                    src="assets/images/icons/invalid-icon.svg"
                    alt="invalid icon"
                  />
                </span>
    <label class="label-top label-employer" for="employer-input">დამსაქმებელი</label
                >
                <input
                  class="input employer-input"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="დამსაქმებელი"
                />
                <label class="label-bottom">მინიმუმ 2 სიმბოლო</label>
  </div>
  <div class="date-container">
    <div class="input-field left-date">
      <label class="label-top label-start-date" for="startdate">დაწყების რიცხვი</label
                  >
                  <input id="startdate" type="date" class="date start_date" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-field right-date">
                  <label class="label-top label-end-date" for="end-date"
                    >დამთავრების რიცხვი</label
                  >
                  <input type="date" id="end-date" class="date end_date" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field about-field">
                <label class="label-top label-description" for="description"
                  >აღწერა</label
                >
                <textarea
                  class="input about-input description"
                  name="about"
                  placeholder="როლი თანამდებობაზე და ზოგადი აღწერა"
                ></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="border-grey-line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="moreExp"></div>
            <div class="more-experience-btn-container">
              <button
                class="more-btn more-experience-btn"
                onclick="add_more_field(this)"
              >
                მეტი გამოცდილების დამატება
              </button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain - in your question - by what means you consider an `<input>` to be valid, and when, and in response to what action(s) or event(s)? I've created an incomplete snippet for you, from the HTML in your question, could you please edit that snippet (click "edit" below your answer, and then "Edit the above snippet" link in the generated preview) to include the JavaScript, to show how it's being called, and tied together?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: No, what we need is the minimum amount of code to show how you're using it, and to reproduce your problem as both I, and the community bot, have already asked.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the JQuery Validation Plugin where you can find the documentation here:

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

The plugin is supposed to be used calling the validate() function over the element you wish to have the validation features (your form).